# AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Tags: python, pandas

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test.xlsx',header=0,sheet_name=["Site 01","Site 08"],usecols="A:O")


df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test-result.xlsx', index=False)
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `sheet_name` with a list or None, you will get a dictionary of `DataFrame`. You have to use `concat` to merge them:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name=['Site 01', 'Site 02'], usecols='A:B')
pd.concat(dfs).to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

Example:

```
>>> dfs
{'Site 01':    col1  col2
 0     1     2
 1     3     4,
 'Site 02':    col1  col2
 0     5     6}

>>> pd.concat(dfs)
           col1  col2
Site 01 0     1     2
        1     3     4
Site 02 0     5     6
```